# layout_weight isn't working properly

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I'm creating a simple layout in Android and I have a problem when displaying.
The fact is that all the elements are not displayed. The fact is there are just the calendar and the timespiker but there are not the others.

This is my code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sms_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_id_sms_pro" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_id_sms_pro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_nb_remainning" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_nb_remainning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_name_sender" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_name_sender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="11" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/sms_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/sms_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the result : [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h30oG.png)

Comment: What happens if you remove the weights? I think that if you set the weight then the height should be "0dp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `0dp` value to height to all views so that layout weight can be adjusted

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

check out the [demo](https://gist.github.com/Pavneet6293/8b87c1e519d112cc5b61be39410a47f8)

Answer (score 0):

I did it but the result is strange :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sms_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_id_sms_pro" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_id_sms_pro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_nb_remainning" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_nb_remainning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sms_name_sender" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_name_sender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="11" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/sms_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/sms_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[new result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y451.png)

Comment: 1st don't put this as answers just update your question ,2nd your views are overlapping simply because there is not enough space for all, you need to either put them in a ScrollView otherwise there can be many other little complex solution you can think of

Comment: your welcome buddy  ,you are free to accept my answer now

Comment: How can I do it ? sry I'm new

Comment: follow the link and see the pic in link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi guy, I'm new so when I want to put +1, I have a message with says I need more than 15 reputations and the number isn't incremented

Comment: see the image https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FLkiIZ.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5234%2Fhow-does-accepting-an-answer-work&docid=7KEkF9vmblR8BM&tbnid=lsrThuSnChOq-M%3A&w=300&h=251&bih=709&biw=1280&ved=0ahUKEwilu967oJbPAhWJLI8KHV_cAh0QMwgmKAgwCA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: great and in future be like this and appreciate other too and they will appreciate you too.happy coading